# .htaccess redirect only URLs contain number and tag at end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect every URLs contain number at end to subdomain :

```
http://example.com/773 to http://blog.example.com/773
```

or

```
http://example.com/482/comment... to http://blog.example.com/482/comment...
```

and redirect urls contain "tag", example :

```
http://example.com/tag/free-psd to http://blog.example.com/tag/free-psd
```

or

```
http://example.com/tag/jquery to http://blog.example.com/tag/jquery
```

and not redirect URLs contain strings like this :

```
http://example.com/web or http://example.com/web/shop or http://example.com/about
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^\/(\d+)$
RewriteRule   (.*)  http://blog.example.com/%1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^\/(\d+)\/comment$
RewriteRule   (.*)  http://blog.example.com/%1/comment

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^\/tag\/(.+)$
RewriteRule   (.*)  http://blog.example.com/tag/%1
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct your RewriteRules with regular expressions to only match the number URLs:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+(/.+)?) http://blog.example.com/$1
```

Likewise for the tag URLs:

```
    RewriteRule ^/(tag/.+) http://blog.example.com/$1
```